# Date picker - load booked dates from database and setSpecificDate array

Tags: php, datepicker

I need some help - I have tried setting setSpecificDate so that the array I fetch (and have formatted) from the db will load correctly. When I print $dates_booked the format is 100% correct "yyyy-mm-dd" - any help / advice will be appreciated.

More info about the datepicker / associated code : http://www.triconsole.com/php/calendar_datepicker.php

Thanks in advance!

My Code:

```
    $datesArray = Array();
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        $datesArray[] =  $row['reserved_date'];  
                        $dates_booked=implode(",",$datesArray); 
                        $arrtrans = array();
                        $arrtrans[","] = '"'.",".'"';
                        $dates_booked = strtr($dates_booked,$arrtrans);
                        $dates_booked= '"'.$dates_booked.'"';
                        } 
                          $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date5", true, false);
                          $myCalendar->setIcon("calendar/images/iconCalendar.gif");
                          $myCalendar->setDate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));
                          $myCalendar->setPath("calendar/");
                          $myCalendar->setYearInterval(2012, 2020);
                          $myCalendar->dateAllow(date("Y-m-d"), '2020-01-01');
                          $myCalendar->setDateFormat('j F Y');
                          //$myCalendar->setHeight(350);
                         // $myCalendar->autoSubmit(true, "form1");
                          $myCalendar->setAlignment('left', 'bottom');    
                          // Problematic Line

$myCalendar->setSpecificDate(array('.$dates_booked.'
                          ), 0, '');
                          $myCalendar->writeScript();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mess:

```
                    $datesArray[] =  $row['reserved_date'];  
                    $dates_booked=implode(",",$datesArray); 
                    $arrtrans = array();
                    $arrtrans[","] = '"'.",".'"';
                    $dates_booked = strtr($dates_booked,$arrtrans);
                    $dates_booked= '"'.$dates_booked.'"';
```

is totally useless. Yuo need only this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $datesArray[] =  $row['reserved_date'];  
}
/* ... */
$myCalendar->setSpecificDate($datesArray);
```